How can I make a touch scrolling button in tkinter?
I have a list of buttons, and I want to make them scroll by touching.
I made a canvas, and it frame contained the buttons. Now, how can I make them scroll?
I have try this :
def on_button_drag_(event):
    global start_y_T
    global current_y
    current_y = event.y
    dy = current_y - start_y_T
    start_y_T = current_y
    #a = sum(isinstance(item, str) for item in menuT)*132
    # Calculate the desired position for the canvas view
    b = aa * 210
    position = types_canvas.yview()[0] + (-dy / b)  # Adjust the divisor to control the scroll speed
    types_canvas.yview_moveto(position)

But the scrolling is too slow, and when I try to make it fast, the scrolling fails.

Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use a Scrollbar?

Do you want something like a widget where you can switch places of buttons? Like in a phone where you can change the place of apps?

no I have buttons I want to make them scrollable like in facebook how the posts scroll
